# Inserting file into other file after pattern

Tags: text-processing

How might I insert the content of the file `a`, followed by a newline,
into the file `b`, after the first line containing `PATTERN`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed '/pattern/{r file_b
a\

:f
n; b f
}' file_a
```

If `file_b` is already terminated by a newline, and you don't want an empty line in the output, omit the `a\` line from the script.

On the last line, the `:f` defines a label, `n` reads a newline (which will be automatically printed since the `-n` option was not given to `sed`), and `b f` branches to the `f` label, creating a loop. All this in order to append `file_b` only after the *first* line matching pattern. If you want to append `file_b` after *each* line matching `pattern`, it's much simpler:

```
sed '/pattern/r file_b' file_a
```

Example:

```
$ cat file_a
first
second
third
fourth
first
second
third
fourth
$ cat file_b
b1
b2
b3

$ sed '/second/{r file_b
:f n; b f }' file_a
first
second
b1
b2
b3
third
fourth
first
second
third
fourth

$ printf "x\ny\nz" >file_c
$ sed '/second/{r file_c
a
:f n; b f }' file_a
first
second
x
y
z
third
fourth
first
second
third
fourth

$ sed '/second/r file_b' file_a
first
second
b1
b2
b3
third
fourth
first
second
b1
b2
b3
third
fourth
```

Another solution would be using `ed(1)` (which surprisingly isn't available by default in modern linux distributions, despite being mandated by POSIX and present in all unix systems since 45 years or so):

```
echo '/pattern/r file_b
w' | ed file_a
```

This will edit `file_a` in place and append a newline if there's any at the end of `file_b`; if you want the output written to another file, change the `w` to `w output_file`.

Comment: Thanks.  Could you please explain the last line?

Comment: So the loop is necessary because there is no exit command?

Comment: No, there is an exit command: `q`. But if you use it, no line that comes after `pattern` in `file_a` will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
sed '/PATTERN/r a' b
```

Comment: You might want to add some explanation to that. Answers with just code and little text can get automatically marked as "low quality"

Comment: This is a subset of [mosvy’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/473755/80216#473760). If you believe that there are problems with that other (earlier) answer that your post resolves, explain that.  (Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.) Otherwise, this answer would appear to add no new information.

Comment: @G-Man - fyi the other answer was deleted (so not visible to users with < 10K rep) at the time RudiC posted this answer.